# Problema con un modal en un componente Angular

Tags: angular, modal, eventos

Tengo un componente Angular V15 con el siguiente código:

```
    <div class="alert my-5" *ngFor="let alert of alerts; let i = index">
        <div class="alert-container" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal3"
            (click)="onEdit(alert.id!)">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="box-shadow-services">
                    <div class="checkbox-wrapper-7">
                        <input class="tgl tgl-ios" [id]="'cb2-'+i" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="alert.isPublished"
                            (change)="onPublishedChange(alert.id!)"
                            (click)="$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopPropagation();togglePublish(alert)" />
                        <label class="tgl-btn" [for]="'cb2-'+i"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="actions-container">
                    <i class="bi bi-x-circle-fill" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); onDelete(alert.id!)"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h5 class="mb-3 alert-title fw-bold">{{ alert.title }}</h5>
            <p class="mb-3 alert-message">{{ alert.message }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Esto tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son alertas. Cuando yo hago click encima de una alerta de despliega un modal con los datos de la alerta para poder editarlos.

No obstante, el checkbox que hay en la esquina superior izquierda, es para publicar o despublicar una alerta, y cuando hago click en dicho checkbox, la acción de publicar/despublicar se realiza, pero me salta el modal como si estuviera haciendo click en el resto de la alerta para ver sus detalles.

Necesito que no se muestre el modal cuando hago click en el checkbox.

Cuando hago click en la 'x' de lado superior derecho, sí que se comporta como debe. Salta otro modal diferente para eliminar la alerta. Ese funcionamiento sí es correcto.

El código referente al checkbox concretamente es este:

```
 <div class="box-shadow-services" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
                <div class="checkbox-wrapper-7">
                    <input class="tgl tgl-ios" [id]="'cb2-'+i" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="alert.isPublished"
                        (change)="onPublishedChange(alert.id!)"
                        (click)="$event.preventDefault(); togglePublish(alert)" />
                    <label class="tgl-btn" [for]="'cb2-'+i"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

creo que el stopPropagation() que hay, realmente no hace nada.

Comment: ¿qué hay en la función stopPropagation()? Seguramente solo tienes que hacer preventDefault y retornar false en ella o puede que debas ponerlo en el evento concreto del checkbox

Comment: @track3r la función stopPropagation() es un método que se puede llamar en un objeto de evento en JavaScript. Se utiliza para detener la propagación del evento a través del DOM. He probado a poner preventDefault en las diferentes etiquetas, pero no hace nada, se sigue desplegando el modal exampleModal3